# Yii2 swift mailer viewpath

Tags: yii2

Как задать путь к файлу представления для swiftmailer ? В main.php пишу

```
'mailer' => [
    'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
    'viewPath' => '@app/test',
    // 'useFileTransport' => true, //for the testing purpose, you need to enable this
]
```

В итоге получаю

> ```
> Exception 'yii\base\InvalidParamException' with message 'The view file does not exist: пропущено/app/views/пропущено //!!!
> ```

Т.е. по прежнему используется путь заданный по дефолту, а не тот который задаю я.

В качестве шаблонизатора использую Smarty, соответственно шаблон задаю так

```
$email = Yii::$app->mailer->compose('email_template.tpl')
//
```

Собственно вопрос, почему?

---

php файлы тоже не видит, следовательно проблема не в шаблонизаторе.

---

Разобрался. В конфиге указал путь к теме

`'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '@theme', // здесь у меня путь к теме
        // 'useFileTransport' => true, //for the testing purpose, you need to enable this
    ]`

И все заработало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так делал. Попробуйте. Должно помочь.

Переопределяем базовый класс для более удобного использования

```
use Yii;
use yii\base\InvalidConfigException;
use yii\base\InvalidParamException;
use yii\mail\MessageInterface;
use yii\swiftmailer\Mailer;

class SwiftMailer extends Mailer {

    public $defaultLayout = "main";

    public $layoutsPath;

    public $viewsPath;

    /** @inheritdoc */
    public function compose($view = null, array $params = []) {
        if (empty($view['view']) || !is_string($view['view'])) {
            throw new InvalidParamException(print_r($view, true));
        }

        if (!empty($view['layout']) && is_string($view['layout'])) {
            $this->setTemplate($view['layout']);
        } else {
            $this->setTemplate($this->defaultLayout);
        }

        $view = $this->setPresentation($view['view']);

        return parent::compose($view, $params);
    }

    private function setTemplate($template) {
        $this->htmlLayout = "{$this->layoutsPath}/html/{$template}";
        $this->textLayout = "{$this->layoutsPath}/text/{$template}";
    }

    private function setPresentation($view) {
        $result = [
            'html' => "{$this->viewsPath}/html/{$view}",
            'text' => "{$this->viewsPath}/text/{$view}",
        ];

        if (!is_readable(Yii::getAlias("{$result['text']}"))) {
            unset($result['text']);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

В конфиге

```
'mailer' => [
    'class' => 'common\components\overload\SwiftMailer',
    'defaultLayout' => 'main',
    'layoutsPath' => '@common/mail/layouts',
    'viewsPath' => '@common/mail/views',
    'useFileTransport' => false,
    'transport' => [
        'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
    ]
```

],

Темплейты и вьюхи писем лежат в

```
common
    mail
        layouts
            html
                main.php
            text
                main.php
        views
            html
                recoveryPassword.php
            text
                recoveryPassword.php
```

Ну и использование.

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose(['layout' => 'main', 'view' => 'recoverPassword'], [
    'user' => $exist_user,
])
    ->setFrom([Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'] => Yii::$app->name . ' robot'])
    ->setTo($exist_user->email)
    ->setSubject(Yii::t('mail', 'Linked to your account {app_name}', ['app_name' => Yii::$app->name]))
    ->send();
```